# Расстояние между блоками CSS

Tags: css

Народ всем привет, есть куча блоков которые через flex соединенны в 2 колонки, суть в том что между этими колонками нужно как то сделать расстояние ибо margin-left и margin-right не подходят из-за смещения краев — вопрос есть ли способ как то разделить их при этом что бы не смещалась правая и левая часть. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: используете чистый css ? или какую то библиотеку (bootstrap, vuetify) ?

Comment: Чистый @radar4ick

Comment: Если например в сетке находится четное количество блоков и на них я использую: column-count: 2; 
-moz-column-count: 2; 
-webkit-column-count: 2; то все выглядит как надо - но как только блоков становится 5 или 7 все плывет.

Comment: Добавьте пожалуйста, описание класса для блока

Comment: Задайте блоку-родителю определённую длину + "display: flex; justify-content: space-between". А нужным блокам длину "width: 48%". Должно помочь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение: Родителю даем: margin: -10px; Блоку: margin: 10px; мы получили и отступы и ровную сетку. Всем спасибо.